# React router history.push updates URL but doesn't update component when used with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using react and redux for my application.
I have my routes defined as follows

```
<HashRouter>
    <div className="container">
        <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </div>
</HashRouter>
```

And I have defined my components as

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Register);
```

Now once the registration is done I want to redirect the user to `login` page. So when the login is successful I am redirecting him to `login` from my `UserAction` function as follows

```
UserService.register(user)
    .then(
            user => {
                dispatch(success());
                history.push('/#/login'); //<== here is the issue
            },
            error => {
                dispatch(failure(error));
            }
        );
```

The `history.push` above changes the URL but doesn't load the `Login` component.

I also tried

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Login));
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Register));
```

But still no luck. Any solution how to fix this?

Note: I am not using `react-router-redux`

Comment: could you try `history.push('/login');`

Comment: I personally don't manipulate history directly. I conditionally render a `<Redirect/>` component and let react-router do it for me. Here are the [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

Answer (score 1):

Why do you even want to change the route with history push?

It easily can be done via `location.hash` method ( since you use HashRouter ) and of course the browser and the react itself is enough intelligent to save it in the history of the browser.

so whenever you want to change the url just use something like :

`location.hash = "/myroute/10/secondroute"`

and remember that you can use `<Link>` component to change the url using react-router itself and not bothering yourself to manage the hash or the history.

Link provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application.

**Usage:**

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

`<Link to="/about">About</Link>`

OR

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/courses',
  search: '?sort=name',
  hash: '#the-hash',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}}/>
```

[More informations](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)

Comment: At least in react-router 4.x, the onClick handler for `<Link>` just [calls history.push()](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js#L52), so switching to a Link is unlikely to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
this.context.router.push('/page');
```

At least can you tell me what's your redux-router version ?

In your index file I suggest you that :

```
import routes from './routes'
    ReactDOM.render((
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={hashHistory} routes={routes}/>
      </Provider>), document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

And in your route file :

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={requireAuth(Home)}/>
    <Route path="signup" component={SignUp}/>
</Route>
```

Do you have errors in your console ?